# Is 'and' ever not a conjunction?

Tags: conjunctions

Certain dictionary definitions of ['and'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/and) in lower-case letters are as a conjunction. In capital letters 'AND' is a noun as a Boolean operator. Below is an example of a request to a sign creator for a sign of symbols for Fish & Chips.

Please give me symbols for: fish, 'fish' and and, '&' and chips, 'chips'.

In that example the word 'and' can be said to appear four times in a row. That first use of 'and' in the example sentence was as a conjunction why was it not a conjunction for the other three uses of the word 'and'? [Other Stack Exchange users commented](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/566213/can-you-say-more-than-four-and-words-in-a-row) about 'and' as something other than a conjunction. What is 'and' other than a conjunction?

Comment: Google **"and parts of speech"** and you get this:  **The word “and” is a very common English word, which is almost always used as a conjunction. However, in some cases, the word can also be used as a noun. ** You will find more helpful responses when you display some prior effort on your part.

Comment: The use of all-caps for Boolean operators is a stylistic choice.

Comment: The first time I encountered the "sign maker" problem was to this effect: "There should be more space between fish and and and and and chips", meaning both spaces between the words were too big. You can speak about any word as a word, and then it's a noun. A sign could read "Please do not touch", and the request for the sign would treat each of those words as a noun, even though none of them is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*and* is almost always a conjunction.  Really, the answer could stop here.

As @RonaldSole's link demonstrates, a dictionary definition for *and* may mention that it can also act as a noun or a modifier when referring to the operation in logic or electronics: *an AND gate*; *we combined the three inputs with two ANDs*.  However, this is a very specialist use.

When @KillingTime said, in a comment on your other question, that *and* wasn't being used as a conjunction, it had nothing to do with the meaning of the specific word *and*.  Absolutely any word can be used in various ways not found in its dictionary definition.  For example:

1. As a noun, meaning "an instance of the word":

> I wrote a sentence with fifteen *and*s in a row. (Shor may have an algorithm, but I have more *and*s!)

Often, we would put the word in italics or quotes, but we don't have to.

2. As an interjection, for emphasis:

> You're never satisfied!  *And, and, and*, you always want more.

Note that these possibilities are available for all words, and they have nothing to do with the meaning or part-of-speech of the specific word *and*:

1. > There are too many *tall*s in this paragraph.

   > I think you should delete the *angrily* in that sentence.

   > Should I put a comma after the first *the* in the name of the band The The?
2. > He said the food was too spicy. *Spicy*! What does he know about cooking?

   > He asked if she was a manager. *A*! She's THE manager!

In summary: unless you're discussing Boolean logic, *and* is always a conjunction.  But every word in the language can be used in ways not covered by its dictionary definition.